# SharePoint 2016 - I have two web parts, side-by-side, of the same Calendar. How can I have one web part default to Month view & the other to Day view?

Tags: 2016, calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar

I have two web part instances of the same calendar, side-by-side, on a page. The default view of this calendar is the Month view, so they both appear identical as the monthly calendar view. I am trying to figure out how to have one web part instance instruct the same calendar to load into the Day view by default.

Is there a way to inject a single web part instance with some kind of code that will have it load into a different view, specifically, the Day view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add or inject any kind of code.  List View Web Parts keep their own view settings, and can have different views than the main list that they refer to.  You can play around with their views and not worry about those changes affecting the main list because they are all local to that particular LVWP.

All you have to do is edit the web part that you want to show the day view for, then "edit the current view", and set the scope to "Day".

Put the page in edit mode and then edit the web part:

[image: screenshot of edit web part menu]

Choose "edit the current view":

[image: screenshot of edit the current view]

Set the default scope to Day:

[image: screenshot of scope settings]

Voila!

[image: screenshot of month and day view side by side]

Comment: That's fantastic!  Thank you so much, Dylan!  I can't believe I never took notice of that setting!  Much appreciated!

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: okay I think I did.  I am new and didnt notice how to right away.  thanks again!